# Bind (iOS) custom UITableVIewSource with Xamarin MVVM-light ObservableTableViewController?

Tags: ios, xamarin, mvvm-light

So I build a table list view like in the flowers example from Laurent Bugnion and all works fine. But what is when I want to use the editing(delete with swipe, etc.) features.

How can I create a table view controller with a custom uitableviewsource?

Comment: There are few examples in mvvmlight's codeplex page, like this one: https://mvvmlight.codeplex.com/SourceControl/latest#Samples/Flowers/Flowers.iOSUnified/DetailsViewController.cs

Answer (score 4):

I just finished implementing a new feature in MVVM Light V next which allows you to do the following.

- Use MyCollection.GetObservableTableViewSource(...) which returns an ObservableTableViewSource.
- Use an optional factory (delegate) that you pass to GetObservableTableViewSource, which allows you to create a brand new class deriving from ObservableTableViewSource, in order to extend and override methods.
- Do the exact same things for CollectionViews with ObservableCollectionViewSource.

I am finishing a sample for these features, and will push the code to Codeplex by the end of the week (including a blog post). This will be released in V5.3 which is slated for ~end of February if all goes well.

What you can do now is something like this (inside a UITableViewController):

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    var c = Vm.Items.GetController(CreateCell, BindCell);
    c.TableView = TableView;
    base.ViewDidLoad();
}
```

but this is not satisfactory because the type of c.TableView is a protected class and so it cannot be extended or easily accessed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create your own TableSource, actual implementation doesn't offer those options.

Comment: Yes, that is right, but than I can not use the binding like in the flowers example (ObserveableController)... Is there any other way to do it?